# Impact of @JsonTypeInfo in REST endpoints when concrete implementations are used

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin, jackson, polymorphism

I'm wondering about the effects of adding a `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")` to an interface.

My use case is that I have an interface Message with many subtypes. I want to be able to deserialize and serialize lists of messages in one endpoint.

My classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
interface Message: Serializable

data class Message1(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

data class Message2(
    val name: String,
    val nickName: String
)
```

And the respective endpoint:

```
@RestController
class MessageController {

    @GetMapping("/messages")
    fun getEndpoints(): List<Message> {
        return listOf(
            Message1("Marco", 22),
            Message2("Polo", "Poli")
        )
    }
}
```

So far so good - but now I want another endpoint that uses one of the explicit classes and I get a serialization error in my test that `@class` is missing - I don't want to send that when I'm using a concrete class anyhow.

```
@RestController
class MessageController {

    @PostMapping("/add1")
    fun add(@RequestBody content: Message1) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.tractive.tap.message.request.RequestDataDTO]: missing type id property '@class'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.tractive.tap.message.request.RequestDataDTO]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 51]
```

Why is the `@class` expected even though I'm using a concrete class? Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is expected because by annotating the class with `@JsonTypeInfo` - via class-interface inheritance - you have explicitly instructed your Jackson to expect this information.

`@JsonTypeInfo` accepts parameter `defaultImpl` of type `Class<?>` that will be used

> if type identifier is either not present, or can not be mapped to a registered type

You could use that to default your deserialisation to one type of message, preferably the most widely used explicitly in your api. For other types, you would still have to include the class info for Jackson.

Comment: okay thanks, it was still weird for me that it needs the `@class` attribute on deserialization of one concrete type - I worked around it now by wrapping the `List<Message>` in a DTO and only adding the annotation to the property of the DTO that contained the list of messages